# xstream attribute interdependencies

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I am pretty new to xstream.
Consider a piece of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<els>
    <el attInt="3" attDbl="1.34525"/>
</els>
```

I need to convert the attDbl attribute shifting the decimal point by the number of places specified by attInt. I dont see how to do it using a convertor as I dont seem to have access to both attributes within the convertor interface. Is this something I can do with a converter or should I be using xslt for this purpose?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A converter acting at the 'el' level does have access to both attributes via the `reader` argument:

```
public class ElConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object unmarshall(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        int attInt = Integer.parseInt(reader.getAttribute("attInt"));
        double attDbl = Double.parseDouble(reader.getAttribute("attDbl"));

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return El.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }
```

Comment: thanks mdi - I can see this now. Sorry when I read the doco my understanding was that converters could only be created on individual attributes which I now see is incorrect - your example is nice and clear.